# Report body not showing in 2016 version of reports

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am running an ASP.NET application which displays SSRS reports.

This works fine in prod., using SQL Server 2012, but on my dev machine I'm running SQL Server 2016 with SSRS 2016.

On here, the report header shows (parameter selection), but no report body.
Instead, I get a rather broken Print Dialog.

Any ideas what has changed between those versions to cause this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the newest version of report viewer (13) to work with SSRS 2016. Microsoft has a preview release available as a nuget package under the name `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview`.

If you are still using SQL Server 2012 or 2014 in production, then I would probably stick with the older report viewer when you deploy your code.

Comment: Not sure how/why there was a problem, as I installed VS, SQL Server et al only about a week or so ago, but apparently some DLLs got into the GAC and caused havoc.... Don't know why this should be the case, as that is what the GAC is there for!!

Comment: Yeah, you will need to either remove the old report viewer assemblies from the GAC, or update your SQL Server Data Tools to the latest version.